# Difference between functions and function literals in ActionScript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, function, function-literal

What is the difference between the following two function definitions in ActionScript 3?

```
f = function(arg) {
  // body
}
```

and

```
function f(arg) {
  // body
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is very little practical difference in the example you have provided. The difference is really at compile time. The one worth noting is that that in first case, f = function, you can redefine the value of f at anytime, while in the second case, redefining f would cause a compiler error.

General best practices is to use the second.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. I'll add that `f` can only be called after the declaration in the first, but in the whole scope in the latter.